# Replacing and substituting characters of the the string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, replace

What is the best way to replace all characters in the string?

1. numbers to `'.'`
2. `'.'` to `';'`
3. `'-'` to `'_'`
4. `'_'` to `'-'`

I used temporary characters to do it. But it is messed up when the temp character itself appeared in the first string.

I also tried `tr` method, and it doesn't work for dash and underline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the dash:

```
print "abc123.-_def.456".tr('-_.0-9', '_\-;.')
//                              here ___^
```

**Output:**

```
abc...;_-def;...
```

Comment: You need to scape the dash, or carefully use it
 str.tr("-0123456789._", "_..........;-")

Comment: Thanks, these solved my problem. I cannot use number range without dash scape; so I think I have to go with one of these.